# Linux shell: why is "open" required in this telnet command

Tags: linux, bash, telnet

I tried to process telnet output in bash and i stumbled upon this syntax to send telnet commands to a server

```
( echo open $host $port
sleep 1
echo $cmd1
sleep 1
) | telnet
```

What i would like to know is why the "open" command is required and why

```
( echo $host $port
...
) | telnet
```

results in a "?Invalid command" error.

Comment: [`man telnet`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/telnet.krb5.1.html). Basically, you can either invoke `telnet` with host and port arguments, or, if you invoke it without arguments, you must connect to the host using the `open` command at the `telnet>` prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...because a hostname is not a valid command name?  There is a big difference between

```
$ telnet host port
```

and

```
$ telnet
telnet> host port
```

Where the latter is what your `echo` command is effectively doing.

The one-liner automatically runs an `open` command, so it is basically equivalent to this:

```
$ telnet
telnet> open host port
```

But I'm not at all sure why you wouldn't just run `telnet host port` in the first place.

Comment: Oh, with your explaination this makes sense to me now. I must have confused the linux shell "open" command with the one from telnet. Thank you very much!

Comment: @sanch3z, if Mark Reed gave you the answer, you should mark it as such.